# How can I boot a specific ISO / Linux distribution image file with VMware

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, vmware-player

I've downloaded all the archives of [this](https://github.com/cogitas3d/Linux3DCS) specific linux distribution and I have unzipped them and then I gave the extracted image file to Vmware,but it says `operating system not found`. I have also tried to open it with :

1. DiskInternal Linux Reader
2. IMG to ISO
3. MagicISO
4. OSFMount
5. UltraISO
6. WinImage

because I wanted to make it bootable,but I haven't been able to do it. The error is always :

> Invalid or unkown image file format

or

> file is not CD image file.

I have also wrote the image to a pen drive using the [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=e) tool and I gave the partition to VMware as a physical disk,but it can't boot,also. What can I do now ? The author does not explain well what to do. He says only :

> Com o auxílio de um programa de clonagem de dados, copie o conteúdo do
> arquivo ISO para um pendrive.
>
> With the help of a data cloning program, copy the contents of the ISO file to a USB stick.

Comment: My portuguese is not so good, but don't they offer to download ISO files at the bottom of the page? If you have a bootable ISO file then you simply insert in your virtual DVD drive and boot with it.

Comment: I tried. it says : "the disk might be corrupted"...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tvdzRvb6ZHxh0Zf41rkgsvU72RogCFmAt8Zt3I4dCAQ/edit